# Display JSON data in Angularjs from Web API. The response has status as field

Tags: angularjs

Below is the JSON which I am getting from API call

```
[{"Status":"Success","Emailid":"john.doe@example.com","BookingCreateDate":"07/04/2015 8:25:14 PM","promocode":"SELF","promovalue":"100.000","BookingUniqId":"0","PromoDescription":"RoomsTonite promotional offer - Save Rs. 100/- on your hotel booking.","CreateDatetime":"2015-07-04 20:25:14","UserName":"Mr.Prakash Maheshwari"},{"Status":"Success","Emailid":"john.doe@example.com","BookingCreateDate":"07/04/2015 8:25:14 PM","promocode":"SELF","promovalue":"100.000","BookingUniqId":"0","PromoDescription":"RoomsTonite promotional offer - Save Rs. 100/- on your hotel booking.","CreateDatetime":"2015-07-04 20:25:14","UserName":"Mr.Prakash Maheshwari"},{"Status":"Success","Emailid":"john.doe@example.com","BookingCreateDate":"07/04/2015 8:25:14 PM","promocode":"SELF","promovalue":"100.000","BookingUniqId":"0","PromoDescription":"RoomsTonite promotional offer - Save Rs. 100/- on your hotel booking.","CreateDatetime":"2015-07-04 20:25:14","UserName":"Mr.Prakash Maheshwari"},{"Status":"Success","Emailid":"john.doe@example.com","BookingCreateDate":"07/04/2015 8:25:14 PM","promocode":"SELF","promovalue":"100.000","BookingUniqId":"0","PromoDescription":"RoomsTonite promotional offer - Save Rs. 100/- on your hotel booking.","CreateDatetime":"2015-07-04 20:25:14","UserName":"Mr.Prakash Maheshwari"}]
```

Angular controller JS:

```
$scope.cashsummary = function () {
                    cashSummaryService.summary($scope.cashSummaryData).then(function (response) {
                            //$location.path('/property');
                            $scope.results = response[0].Emailid; alert($scope.results);
                    }, function (err) {
                        $scope.message = err.error_description;
                    });
            }; $scope.cashsummary();
```

I want to display only fields like `Emailid`, `promocode`,`usename`in AngualrJS view. While I am calling service from controller I am getting above format JSON

Comment: Please paste some code you have tried.

Comment: What have u tried so far??

Comment: It's crazy easy and you probably didn't search solution, just posted question, it's just an array with single object `arr[0].Emailid`

Comment: I tried it. It is showing undefined. Below is my angularjs controller code

Comment: @SubrataDey post all your input code on question itself not as comment. That will get more attention ⚠ from users

Answer (score 1):

```
// write this in controller
 var data=//take all json data into this variable
 var totList=[];
 for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  var disp={
            Emailid:data[i].Emailid,
            promocode:data[i].promocode,
            usename:data[i]UserName

        }
     totList.push(disp);

    if(i==data.length-1){
     $scope.profileList=totList;
        }  
       }


 //html for this


  <ion-view >
  <ion-nav-title> </ion-nav-title>

<ion-content>
<ion-list>
   <ion-item ng-repeat="profileList in profileList">
      {{profileList.Emailid}}
      {{profileList.promocode}}
      {{profileList.usename}}


   </ion-item>


    </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
   </ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, this is a very basic example (it's given in the home page of [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)) and this question should be closed but you can simply do this like below:

```js
angular.module("sa", []).controller('foo', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.cashsummary = function() {
    // var url = serviceBase + cashSummaryUrl;
    var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
      $scope.results = data;
    })
  };

  $scope.cashsummary();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="foo">
  <div ng-repeat="result in results">
    Email ID: {{result.email}}
    <br>Code: {{result.website}}<br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The response is coming from webapi in a single string. So how can I make the things in controller whatever you have written. Here is the service call in angular  $http.get(serviceBase + cashSummaryUrl).success(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(JSON.stringify(response));
        }).error(function (err, status) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        })